# Open.closed, and connected sets.

Tags: general-topology

> {z ∈ $\mathbb{C}$ | Re(z) < −1 or Re(z) > 4}
>
> Show whether it is open, closed or neither and if it is connected

Own work:

The set can be expressed as:

{z ∈ $\mathbb{C}$ | Re(z) < −1} ∪ {z ∈ $\mathbb{C}$ | Re(z) > 4}

These two sets are seen to be non-empty, open and disjoint hence not connected.
Alternatively, any path from a Re(z)>4 and Re(z)<-1 must pass through a point whose real part is 0, contradicting the Intermediate Value theorem.

Is this correct? And how do I show the two sets expressed are open if they are so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, to show that these sets are open let $Re(z)>4$ take $\varepsilon=Re(z)-4$,  then $Re(z_0)>4$ for any $z_0\in B(z,\varepsilon)$. The other one is similar and easy if you understand this case.

Comment: To show the other one is open is the proof, Re(z)<-1  take ε=Re(z)+1 , then Re(z)<-1  for any z∈B(z,ε). is this correct? I think i followed a similar approach to your proof

Comment: I think $\varepsilon=-1-Re(z)$ would be the appropriate value for $\varepsilon$. Remember that $\varepsilon$ must be positive, the value you chose is not.